# Importing multiple events to Outlook 2003 in one .ics file

Tags: calendar, outlook

I have a web app that contains many specific events for users in a MySQL database.  I want to generate one .ics file that users can download that contains all of these events.

I'm not able to get Microsoft Outlook 2003 to acknowledge anything past the first event in my ICS file.  Are there any known workarounds for this issue? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Here's my ICS file contents:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120222T120000
DTEND:20120222T123000
SUMMARY:Event Name 1
LOCATION:
DESCRIPTION:This is the description of event 1.
PRIORITY:3
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120223T120000
DTEND:20120223T123000
SUMMARY:Event Name 2
LOCATION:
DESCRIPTION:This is the description of event 2.
PRIORITY:3
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120224T120000
DTEND:20120224T123000
SUMMARY:Event Name 3
LOCATION:
DESCRIPTION:This is the description of event 3.
PRIORITY:3
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with only one calendar with multiple events:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120222T120000
DTEND:20120222T123000
SUMMARY:Event Name 1
LOCATION:
DESCRIPTION:This is the description of event 1.
PRIORITY:3
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120223T120000
DTEND:20120223T123000
SUMMARY:Event Name 2
LOCATION:
DESCRIPTION:This is the description of event 2.
PRIORITY:3
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```