# Outlook not importing multiple events from the same .ics

Tags: outlook, icalendar

This question has been asked before and I apologise in advance for reposting, but none of the solutions are working.

I am trying to create a .ics file containing multiple events (not a recurrence) and send it to my users from php. All the email clients import the events fine, except Outlook, which only adds the first event and ignores the rest. I have tried multiple solutions from stackoverflow, including:

> [Outlook not importing multiple events in an ics file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863557/outlook-not-importing-multiple-events-in-an-ics-file)

and

> [Importing multiple events to Outlook 2003 in one .ics file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297700/importing-multiple-events-to-outlook-2003-in-one-ics-file)

and many others from various websites. I tried switching the method from REQUEST to PUBLISH, adding X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN=TRUE, X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE and combinations between them.

Can you please take a look at my generated .ics and tell me what I'm doing wrong:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//somedomain.com//SOMEDOMAIN//EN
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN=TRUE
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/London
TIMEZONE-ID:Europe/London
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:152022081811@somedomain.com
DTSTAMP:20220818T064006Z
DTSTART:20220818T070000Z
DTEND:20220818T170000Z
SUMMARY:Desk booking
LOCATION:Headquarters / #1st Floor / Desk 1.4
ORGANIZER;CN="AM Gmail":mailto:calendar+15@somedomain.com
DESCRIPTION:"DESCRIPTION 1"
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=CHAIR;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE;CN="AM Outlook":mailto:test@somedomain.com
STATUS:CONFIRMED
URL:https://localhost/spaces/view/15
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:152022081922@somedomain.com
DTSTAMP:20220818T064006Z
DTSTART:20220819T070000Z
DTEND:20220819T170000Z
SUMMARY:Desk booking
LOCATION:Headquarters / #1st Floor / Desk 1.4
ORGANIZER;CN="AM Gmail":mailto:calendar+15@somedomain.com
DESCRIPTION:"DESCRIPTION 2"
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=CHAIR;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE;CN="AM Outlook":mailto:test@somedomain.com
STATUS:CONFIRMED
URL:https://localhost/spaces/view/15
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook not importing multiple events in an ics file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863557/outlook-not-importing-multiple-events-in-an-ics-file)

Comment: @Justinas - The OP mentioned that they already tried that specific question/solution though, but it didn't work.